# Handle response of multiple request from Volley Library

Tags: android, android-volley

I am sending multiple request through for loop.

On response I get success or failure message, and I need to show this message in a `AlertDialog`.

My Problem is: when I am sending 10 request then I am getting 10 response hence 10 times dialogue is showing with response.

I want to show only one dialogue when all response will have come,and that dialogue should contain response according to their each and every request.

How can I do it.

code which I tried:

```
if (globalInstance.isNetworkAvailable(AddBookingList.this)) {
                            int si = checkedItems.size();
                            if (checkedItems.size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < si; i++) {
                                    int appid = checkedItems.get(i).getAppid();
                                    int bookingId = checkedItems.get(i).getBookingid();
                                    List<Contacts> con = db.getadvertisment(bookingId);
                                    List<AddImages> img = db.getImagesbybookingId(bookingId);
                                    String postXml = createxmlForPost(con, img);
                                    sendDataToServer(postXml,appid, bookingId, si);
                                }

                            }

                        }




 private void sendDataToServer(final String postXml, final int appid, final int bookingId, final int si) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        try {
            final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("xmlData", postXml);
            int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds
            final StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.Rootpath + "PostBooking",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String st) {
                            if (progressDialog != null || progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            try {
                                JSONArray response = new JSONArray(st);
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    int status = jsonObject.getInt("Status");
                                    String msg = jsonObject.getString("Msg");
                                    String serverbooking_id = jsonObject.getString("BookingId");
                                    if (status == 1) {
                                        checkedItems.clear();
                                        if (response.length() > 1) {
                                            String newserverbooking_id = response.getJSONObject(0).getString("BookingId") + "\n" + response.getJSONObject(1).getString("BookingId");
                                            db.updateBookingDetailsbyAppId(newserverbooking_id, appid, status);
                                        } else {
                                            db.updateBookingDetailsbyAppId(serverbooking_id, appid, status);
                                        }
                                        showDatainList();

                                        globalInstance.showSuceessMessage(true, "Success!!! Your BookingID is: " + serverbooking_id, AddBookingList.this);
                                        try {
                                            List<Contacts> contacts = db.getAllBookingDetails();
                                            for (int h = 0; h < contacts.size(); h++) {
                                                locallySaveImagesinPhone(bookingId, contacts.get(h).get_serverbookingId());
                                            }
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        globalInstance.showFailureMessage(false, "Booking Failed." + msg, AddBookingList.this);

                                        checkedItems.clear();
                                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                               }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            if (progressDialog != null || progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            String msg = error.getMessage();
                            globalInstance.showFailureMessage(false, "Booking Failed.Please Try Again!!!", AddBookingList.this);
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("xmldata", postXml);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
            queue.add(postRequest);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is t he alert dialog locateD?

Comment: when i get the response then on activity i need to show success message with some id.

Comment: You mean progressDialog?

Comment: progress dialog started when i start to send request,and dismiss when reponse will be come. but response mesaage and some id will be show in a Alertdialog.

Comment: Have you tried taking out the progress dialog inside the loop?

Comment: but my problem is not progress dialog,i will do it.My problem is how to show response in a single alert dialog of all request.

Comment: Make a list of responses, and on your last response show the dialog with the information available in list. This can be done this way

Comment: when i  am taking out the progress dialog from loop then when i will stop this loop,how can i know all the response will be come.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem is calling  `globalInstance.showSuceessMessage()` or `globalInstance.showFailureMessage` every time you get the response.

what i think might work is:

1. Instead of these two methods, define an `Arraylist<String>` and based on the
   success or failure of the response add messages to it like `"Success!!! Your BookingID is: " + serverbooking_id` and `"Booking Failed." + msg`.
2. Define a method like `showMessages()` which has a dialogue containing the messages u added to arraylist before. then call it after where you called the`sendDataToServer` method which is in the `if (checkedItems.size() > 0)` block.